# Is there a word for state of residence?

Tags: single-word-requests

One’s nationality is the status of belonging to a particular nation.

One’s status of belonging to a particular US state is called what?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You might be a *native* of a state because you are from there ("from" being defined differently by different people) or a *resident* because you currently live there, but there is no concept that corresponds exactly to nationality because the American legal and political system does not treat association with a state in the same way that international law governs association with a country. Your question might be improved if you could explain what concept you are trying to express.

Comment: @choster I was putting somebody’s profile into a table and used the word ‘residence’ to label the entry for the state they live in. I want to know if there is a more specific word that I can use to make it more explicit and easy for people to know its what state they live in, not the city, country, etc

Comment: *Nationality* does not refer to residence, so the question as worded is unclear; please [edit] it. You might benefit from reading the [guidance for single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) as well. Generally, requests for help with naming or labeling are not well-received here, but if you can formulate an example sentence that would use this word, someone might be able to help. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use **state**.

That's exactly what's used on forms that ask people what state they live in.

Answer (score -1):

From a legal point of view, the word is *citizenship.*  From the 14th amendment:

> All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States and of the State wherein they reside.

A US citizen who resides in California is, therefore, a citizen of California.

From the point of view of your database, however, I would use *state of residence* or *residence state.*  Using just *state* could be confusing if there are also mailing addresses in the table.